# iPhone scam message - did not open picture but pressed preview

Tags: iphone, messages, spam

I have made a mistake tonight. I received a picture message, saying "free picture message - click to open'. I did not click the link in the message, but I did click "preview". Nothing happened on my phone afterwards and I didn't get taken to any websites (or Safari).

I Googled the phone number that sent me the message afterwards and realised the message was from spammers. I am asking if anybody knows what it means to "preview" the message on an iPhone - has it downloaded it to your phone?

Any help would be gratefully received - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you see it on your screen, it has been downloaded (would be difficult to show something which has not been downloaded). It doesn't matter whether you just preview something or open it in an app, technically there is no real difference.

The question behind the question probably is "should I worry?". Nobody can say for sure without much more information about the specific content, but most probably "no, not all all".